# C# reading text file from certain location to EOF

Tags: c#, readline, eof

Trying to find a good way to read a text file and find the last instance of a certain phrase and read the file to the end from that point.

example simplified

```
sometext1...
sometext2...
[new]
sometext3...
[new]
sometext4...
sometext5...
[new]
sometext6...
sometext7...
```

Want i want returned is the last part written

```
[new]
sometext6...
sometext7...
```

I can think of ways to do this, but i'm sure there is a very efficient way.
Guessing would have to find the last index of "[new]" and read from there.

Comment: could you show any code that you have attempted to write to solve this problem

Comment: How big is the file? How fast does it have to be? Is the phrase always just one line?

Comment: Jon's sanwser below worked just like i needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming:

1. [new] is always on a line of its own.
2. None of the lines are massive.
3. Each chunk is reasonably small (not a massive memory burden in themselves).
4. The file could be very large, so you don't want to read the whole thing into memory.

Then I would do the following. Change the first three assumptions and it gets trickier, change the fourth and I'd be lazy and just load the whole thing in:

```
using(TextReader tr = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(string line = tr.ReadLine(); line != null; line = tr.ReadLine())
        if(line == "[new]")
            sb = new StringBuilder("[new]");//flush last chunk read.
        else
            sb.Append('\n').Append(line);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks worked perfect. Its just a real simple text file(logging) and just want to show the last entry. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
var text =  File.ReadAllText(theFile);
var tail = text.SubString(text.LastIndexOf("[New]"));
```

Comment: This was close, but the index was only for line 1. Did not handle newline and return chars.

Answer (score 1):

You can open a file stream, wrap it into TextReader, then save value of Position property in FileStream instance. It allows you to save positions of [new] tokens.